# Simple solution to create a zip for Windows users without __MACOSX or any other "period" hidden folders

Tags: macos, mac, finder, zip

I've seen questions:

- [How can I create a zip archive for Windows and Linux users?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102454/how-can-i-create-a-zip-archive-for-windows-and-linux-users)
- [How to remove __MACOSX folder in a list of zip files (not a single zip file)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242684/how-to-remove-macosx-folder-in-a-list-of-zip-files-not-a-single-zip-file)
- [How can I batch zip multiple folders without _macosx files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300268/how-can-i-batch-zip-multiple-folders-without-macosx-files)

This question is different.

I'm asking for a way to create a zip without the `.DS_Store` or  `__MACOSX` for less sophisticated Apple computer users who have to coexist with Windows users who cannot accept a zip with the `.DS_Store` and `__MACOSX`.

I've discovered these are called Mac resource forks.

**Like I said, for less sophisticated Apple users, so no command line codes please.**

Comment: [BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com) Not cheap, but really simple.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think thats an up-votable answer not a comment

Comment: I wasn't sure about posting a recommendation to a 25 buck zip application as an answer... but if you like the idea, i can do that.

Comment: @Tetsujin after looking at the price tag I have to agree with you. It's better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having to use terminal,
you could try [Folderwasher](https://sw.ixoft.com/folderwasher/), which is an app that creats a zip without the .DS_store file. You can drop the folder onto the application and it compresses it.

Alternatively, you could try [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/), which also has an option to exclude the .DS_store file. Open Keka, click on zip, and check `Exclude Mac OS X resource forks` and drop what you want to compress on the Keka window.

There are other questions related to this topic:

- [Compressing folders on a mac, without the .DS_Store](https://superuser.com/a/198584/438940) on Superuser
- [Compress without .DS_Store and __MACOSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264924/122152) on AskDifferent

Comment: I wish I could give you +2 for Folderwasher and Keka.

A simple solution to deleting all the unwanted period folders we have in Windows now.

Keka confirmed working